# Import Error No module named request_oauthlib

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi.

I have imported Twython properly, but every time I run

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer
```

I get the following error

> no module named request_oauthlib error.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Could `request_oathlib` possibly be a typo, and should be `request_oauthlib` instead?

Comment: Sorry! It should be request_oauthlib. A typo on my part. Thanks

Comment: @BaasilPasha you should try to install Twython throug `pip`. Using pip allows you to install all other linked libraries Twython needs.

Comment: pip install requests requests_oauthlib

Comment: @StefanE I'm using python3 and the lib dependancies are automatically installed see pic -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nzAd.jpg

Comment: @BaasilPasha which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @AndyK Agree with your commented, just wanted to give some help to specifically solve the problem he got..

Comment: @StefanE no worries. OP did not mention if he was using 2 or 3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `TwythonStreamer` needs a dependency package called `request_oauthlib` which was not installed while you installed `twython`.

You just need to install `request_oauthlib` to solve the problem.